# Can I avoid travelling to the Schengen country whose embassy issued me the visa?

Tags: multiple-entry, schengen-visas

I am a non-EU resident currently residing in London, UK. I hold a multiple-entry Schengen visa holder issued by the French Embassy. Unfortunately my entire itinerary has changed and I am not visiting any countries submitted to the French Embassy. 
My Paris trip got postponed and I will be visiting Paris, France in the subsequent month and not in the first trip.

My query is are there any serious consequences or any repercussions if I visit any other countries and not the one in the itinerary given to them. How should I tackle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @chx, I don't think it is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

- If the visa officials believe that the initial application was fraudulent, you have a problem. There have been issues especially with single-entry visa, that depends on how vigilant/concerned the entry officials in your new destination are.
- If the visa officials believe that you are adjusting your itinerary in good faith, that's what the Schengen area and multiple-entry visa are all about, and you have no problem.

I don't think we can give you firm assurances without knowing more. If you are really worried, take the train to your first trip, that will get you a French entry stamp.

Comment: "If you are really worried, take the train to your first trip" Or bus if on a Budget. Also bear in mind the French are frequently lazy about stamping, in which case you **must** explicitly ask them to